# Skip a list of migrations in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have migrations `0001_something`, `0002_something`, `0003_something` in a third-party app and all of them are applied to the database by my own app. I simply want to skip these three migrations. One option is to run the following command

`python manage.py migrate <third_party_app_name> 0003 --fake`

But I don't want to run this command manually. I was thinking if there can be any method by which I can specify something in settings to skip these migrations. I would simply run `python manage.py migrate` and it would automatically recognize that 3 migrations need to be faked. Or if there is any way to always fake `0001`, `0002` and `0003`.

If this was in my own app, I could simply remove the migration files but it is a third party app installed via. `pip` and I don't want to change that.

Comment: `python manage.py migrate <third_party_app_name>  --fake ` to skip all migrations ?

Comment: @itzmeontv Ya that will work. But as I specified I don't want to run the migration manually. I was looking if running `python manage.py migrate` will automatically recognize that three migrations need to be migrated.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do that.Try

- Add entries in `django_migrations` table like

  ```
  app                 name                         applied
  <thirdpartyname>    003_something #without .py   2014-04-16 14:12:30.839899+08 #some date before now
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The [`MIGRATION_MODULES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#migration-modules) setting lets you specify an alternative module for an app's migrations. You could set this for your app, then leave out the migrations you wish to skip, or replace them with empty migrations.

Comment: This is really useful. This can ignore all migrations in an application. Is there any way we can specify which migrations to ignore?

Comment: No, this approach does not let you specify which migrations to ignore. You can create a migrations directory inside your project, copy the migrations from the app that you do wish to use, and leave out the ones that you don't want. Then use the `MIGRATION_MODULES` setting so that Django uses your migrations module.

Comment: This looks to be best approach. I have copied the migrations and put it into my own app. I simply want to include new migrations in case an update in the app creates new migrations.

Comment: There isn't a way to automatically copy new migrations from the app to your migrations module. You'll have to manage that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The django knows about applied migrations is only through migration history table. So if there is no record about applied migration it will think that this migration is not applied. Django does not check real db state against migration files.

Comment: This is the same code I have specified on my question. And if possible I want to simply avoid this .

Comment: @SudipKafle The main point of this answer that. This is not possible. Because django's only way to know about migrations is through django_migrations table.